# Powershell -contains/-notcontains - having trouble with an array result from SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using Invoke-SQLCmd to get a list of items that I want to process. In that list may be an item that indicates that the entire list needs to be bypassed. I have tried to figure out how to use the -contains and -notcontains operator but I am not having any luck. This would be the pseudo code:

```
$dont_process = "dont process"
$list = Invoke-SQLCmd ........
if ($list -notcontains $dont_process) {processing goes here}
```

$list is a System.array of DataRows. The operator is supposed to work on an array but I guess an array of DataRows is not the kind it works on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$dont_process` variable is a string, is it not?  The `-contains` and `-notcontains` operators use the `-eq` operator on each item in the list.  The `-eq` operator is a .Net comparison, so the DataRow class must support a comparison between between a DataRow and a string.  According to MSDN, it [does not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(VS.71).aspx).

In fact, I'm not entirely sure how you'd compare a DataRow and a string.  Would it be the name of the first Item in the row?

For the purposes of this answer, let's pretend you want to compare the `.ToString()` of the DataRow.

You'll probably have to resort to the more-longwinded way of doing things:

```
$list = Invoke-SQLCmd ...

$dontProcess = "dont process"
$shouldProcess = $true    
$foreach ($dataRow in $list) { 
    if ($dataRow.ToString() -eq $dontProcess) { 
        $shouldProcess=$false; 
    } 
}

if($shouldProcess) {
    # processing goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Actually, I did more searching over the weekend and found this, which works nicely also
    $list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $dont_process = "dont_process"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd ......| foreach {[Voidd] $$list.add($_.name)}
    If ($list -cnotontains $dont_process) {#process here}